# null is not an object (evaluating 'teachers.length')

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

```
const [teachers, setTeachers] = useState([]);

    const teachersList = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@teachers_list');
        if (!storedValue) {
            setTeachers([]);
        }
        const list = JSON.parse(storedValue);
        setTeachers(list);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        teachersList();
    }, [isFocused])

return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>
                {teachers.length == 0 ? (
                    <View style={styles.noData}>
                        <Text>Teacher List Empty</Text>
                    </View>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {
                            teachers.map((teacher) => (
                                <View key={teacher.id} style={styles.productContainer} >
                                    <View style={styles.productDetails}>
                                        <Text> Name : {teacher.name}</Text>
                                        <Text> Subject : {teacher.subject}</Text>
                                        <Text> Email : {teacher.email}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.productButtonContainer}>
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.productActionEditButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Edit", { teacher })}>
                                            <Text> Edit </Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.productActionDelButton} onPress={() => deleteTeacher(teacher.id)}>
                                            <Text> Delete </Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            ))
                        }
                    </>
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
```

The following code giving me an error. It was working when I was creating this application but now it's not working and showing me this error. I tried `teachers && (code)` but it is not working

> null is not an object (evaluating 'teachers.length')

Comment: Have you tried console logging the value of teachers? If it's actually null, something in your code is calling setTeachers with a null parameter, because by default you set it to an empty array which, clearly, has length of 0.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using something like useEffect that calls setTeachers

Comment: You have to show all usages of setTeachers

Comment: here I'm fetching data from Asyncstorage and saving it in teachers..then I'm mapping that list

Comment: @windowsill done

Comment: Please see the JSON parsed data. The list variable might not be an array. Try finding out the type of list variable.
```console.log("Type of list" , typeof(list))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  I just had to re-think the requirements of what you are doing

Instead of this:

```
teachers.length == 0 ? (
 <View style={styles.noData}>
     <Text>Teacher List Empty</Text>
</View>
       )
```

try using this:

```
!teachers || teachers.length == 0 ? (                     
<View style={styles.noData}>                         
<Text>Teacher List Empty</Text>                    
 </View>                 
)
```

Comment: If you expect teachers to always be an object, then doing this is hiding unexpected behavior. The real answer is that you need to do `setTeachers([]); return;` because you are continuing to execute that function, then setting it to null.